# sending packed iso messages with mux

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I need to send a packed iso message, i.e. message of type byte[] over a channel. But I need to use the MUX

```
ISOMsg responce = mux.request(m, 10000);

    if (responce != null){

        //we have a responce
    }
    else{

        //we retransmit or send a reversal
    }
```

but that 'm' in the MUX request I need it to be packed. Up to now I have been sending my messages like this:

```
m.setPackager(packager);
byte[] data = m.pack();
channel.send(data);
```

and its been working great but now I want to hanlde revesals and I am not sure how to do that. Is there a way to send a packed message over the wire and set a timeout like I would do with the MUX?

Comment: Mux do not understand byte arrays, it doesn't know how to interpret them to handle the keys to match respones with requests, so you'll have to send ISOMsg instances. Sending packed messages directly through the channel isn't a good practice either. If you need to match responses to requests using muxes, you will have to send the ISOMsgs and let the channel pack them.

Comment: @Andrés Alcarraz Okay then Thanks!

Comment: @Andrés Alcarraz Thank you for you reply, that was really helpful. I was going about it the wrong way and now I am using the mux effectively. Thanks